# Syntax error: newline unexpected - QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-12.04, qt-creator

I want to develop some Qt applications with QtCreator IDE on Ubuntu 12.04. When I'm trying to build even the most simple project, I get this error:

> /home/jerzu/QtTest/qt-test/mainwindow.ui:-1: error: 2:
>   ../qt-test/mainwindow.ui: Syntax error: newline unexpected

And when I'm using command line (`qmake2 ProjectName.pro` command), everything goes well. I'm sure that the `qmake` path in QtCreator is correct.

Have you any idea, what's going on?

EDIT:

#### mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

#### output line

> 17:23:26: Running steps for project QtTest...
>   17:23:26: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>   17:23:26: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
>   ../QtTest/mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
>   ../QtTest/mainwindow.ui: 2: ../QtTest/mainwindow.ui: Syntax error: newline unexpected
>   make: *** [ui_mainwindow.h] Error 2
>   17:23:26: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project QtTest (kit: Beagle-xM2)
>   When executing step 'Make'

EDIT2:

#### Makefile:

http://shrib.com/CBm2rKJV

Comment: Can you post the contents of the ui file? A simple project that demonstrates the error is preferred.

Comment: I don't think that adding my whole project is necessary, because it's just a default QtCreator project, which you get, when you select File->New file or Project->Qt GUI Application etc. That's just one empty window, nothing more...

Comment: From the error message, seems like it is trying to run `make` as if it were `uic`. Something is really wrong with your environment.

Comment: Ok, show us the makefile that qmake generated.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answers! I'm pretty sure that my problem is some basic issue and it's all about environment setup or something like that... I've posted the Makefile above, maybe it will tell you something more.

Comment: How did you install qt and qt-creator?

Comment: Did you turn Shadow build off?

Comment: That is a really weird setup. First off, that's quite an old version of Qt (4.6.3). And then it seems you're using some Qt mkspecs for embedded platforms or something like that. You should check Qt version in Qt Creator again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your support, I've finally resolved my problem. Like Guilherme said, it was all about environment setup... I had to reconfigure and correct some Kit options, especially compilers paths, and choose good version of `qmake` to work with every single compiler I set.

Little hint for these, which would build applications for BeagleBoard and use `angstrom-linux-gnueabi` toolchain:

Until you fire QtCreator, you **MUST** run `(...)/angstrom/arm/environment-setup`! And then, start QtCreator **FROM CONSOLE**. This is what I had to do to get properly working environment.

Regards
jerzu

Comment: Maybe you want to accept your own answer now, so that this Question will not show up as unanswered anymore :)

Comment: Yep ;) Sorry, I'm quite new here ;)